# Visual Basic Pointers

Tags: vba, pointers

Can you give me an example on how to make pointers and use them to manipulate the value they point at? Can you give me a string and a numeric example in visual basic? Can you send me a link to more information and a pointer reference (preferably MSDN)?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5685/Pointers-in-Visual-Basic-using-Undocumented-Functi

Answer (score 1):

Pointers can be simulated using various techniques, but there is no native pointers support in VB. See more here: [Vb.net Pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/759474/vb-net-pointers)

Comment: I believe that article only relates to the .Net framework rather than old skool VBA.

Comment: @AlanK you're right but it's the same for the concept of pointers

Answer (score 0):

VBA isn't a C family language (obviously), so as Icepack said pointers aren't really natively supported. You can take a look at the following articles:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/199824

(Though that's for VB rather than VBA; I've used some of those functions in VB6 myself but not VBA so I can't guarantee that any or all will work) and for the sake of completeness to get the address of a function:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa165194%28v=office.10%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks to whoever downvoted the previous upvote that I received for this answer without, naturally, leaving any indication of what your issue was with the reply. (For that would have actually been constructive and we couldn't have that; far better to skulk around sniping at answers from the darkness while contributing nothing yourself.) I am, however, happy to note that it cost you as much reputation to do it as it cost me.