# What is equivalent "stackalloc" in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I have the following code in `C#` below:

```
short* gArray = stackalloc short[3 * 256];
```

would like the equivalent in `VB.net`

I tried to do the conversion, with some different online tools, but it only returns me as a type of Invalid Syntax and / or does not exist for the VB.net syntax structure.

If it is possible to chat between syntaxes, as I do in a simplified way (any other types of code, such as Integers, Booleans, among others)

---

This is the complete code used in `C#`

```
public static unsafe bool SetBrightness(int brightnessValue)
{
    if (brightnessValue > 255)
        brightnessValue = 255;
    if (brightnessValue < 0)
        brightnessValue = 0;
    short* gArray = stackalloc short[3 * 256];
    short* idx = gArray;
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
        {
            int arrayVal = i * (brightnessValue + 128);
            if (arrayVal > 65535)
                arrayVal = 65535;
            *idx = (short)arrayVal;
            idx++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's `unsafe` code.  There is no such thing in VB.NET.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use unsafe code in VB.Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5915874/how-can-i-use-unsafe-code-in-vb-net)

Comment: There is some alternative, at least reading this https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d8451bf7-f9bd-49d5-939e-030d7d1e70f8/what-is-equivalent-of-stackalloc-in-vbnet but if it works for you probably depends on your exact context

Comment: In general, you shouldn't care about where memory is allocated, either in C# or VB.NET.  Unsafe code in C# only exists for very specific use cases.

Comment: I updated my question by inserting the context code using it in my application, so that you can better understand what I want ... only if **conversion** is possible or not, use the same function as ```C#``` in ```VB.net```

Comment: It's not.  Not directly, anyway.  Does this C# code satisfy some *measurable* performance constraint?

Comment: This code looks like it could be replaced with shifts and boolean bit logic.  If so, you could eliminate the loop.  It might actually run faster than the `unsafe` code in that form.  It would be helpful if we knew what this code actually does, e.g. is it converting to RGB via some well-known algorithm?

Comment: @RobertHarvey No, no, just comparing and multiplying the values to reach a certain percentage (between 0 and 65535)

Comment: If there's no performance constraints, you can just rewrite it without the `stackalloc`.  But you do need to mind the pointer arithmetic; you don't get that in VB.NET.

Comment: Did you get that code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48657889/102937)?

Comment: @RobertHarvey That, with some changes, but yes!

Comment: i think you should take a look at this, we don't have that in VB.Net : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/759474/vb-net-pointers

Comment: That particular Stack Overflow post has other answers in it that do not require `unsafe` code.

Comment: @RobertHarvey just like I did not understand?